# Sensing weather conditions through bodily reactions (e.g. dry hands, arthritic pains)

Tags: pathology, human-physiology, sensation, perception

Two fairly known examples of the effect of certain weather conditions on the body are dry hands due to decreased air humidity around us (more commonly in the winter, as described [here](http://www.webmd.com/beauty/features/prevent-soothe-chapped-winter-hands#1)), and flaring of arthritis immediately before or after it rains (as described [here](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/2012/06/the-weather-and-arthritis-does-rain-increase-pain/) and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25342437)).

I was wondering if there are more examples of this kind, when what I am specifically looking for are bodily reactions through which one might be able to forecast or know something about the weather (i.e. if you have arthritis, you might be able to know it is going to rain sometime soon according to what you feel in your legs; if your hands are dry and chapped, you know that the air is drier than usual).

Comment: There is no scientific evidence for weather pains.

Comment: @JM97 Actually there is some scientific evidence, and in fact the OP linked to some studies showing that evidence. However, it is certainly true that there is not scientific *consensus* and studies I am familiar with show peoples' perceptions to be very exaggerated vs the actual evidence.

Comment: It's sad to see these close votes. Arguably this could be a Skeptics. SE question, but it is very interesting as weather related pains are a widely known phenomenon in rheumatic patients.

Comment: Thank you all for your interest. I saw people voted to close the question because it is "too broad". Since I didn't emphasize it, some people may have overlooked the fact that I was asking for more examples, i.e. if anyone knows of such examples they could post them as an answer or a comment. Is it really "too broad"? Perhaps this question doesn't have a single definite answer (or an answer at all), but I don't think it is too broad as phrased. As for skepticism, it COULD be an interesting subject for discussion, but that wasn't my original intention.